# Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express - the system can not find the file specified

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++

I installed Visual Studio on Windows XP, I created project and imported files in it. E.g. when I click on the header file which I imported in the "Header Files" then the document is not opened in the VS but in new window of Notepad! I am absolutely confused why this is. This is same with the cpp files. When I try to compile the project I got many error which probably should not happen because the files were compiled in previous project in previous instalation of VS on different machine. So the file should be OK. So when I got an error in Output window, i lick on the error to open the file, but here I go the error which is shown in status bar: the system can not find the file specified. I can copy the path from Output box and open the file in Notepad.

Note: The files .h and .cpp have correct are assigned to Visual Studio, but it was originally assigned to CodeBlocks. Also: I can open different project which I downloaded from internet and those file are opened with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The file contained non-valid characters which was not visible. This happened because I undeleted the file. I needed to remove all not valid characters from the file. Now VS can open the file.